# Recommended eMail headers and content that help reduce bouncing

Tags: email, spam-prevention, email-spam, php

It seems now, more than ever, the major service providers have cracked down on SPAM and really focused on filtering.

This is a huge concern for website's that require email validation, as users who do not receive instant emails are generally put-off the service all together.

So, my question is;

***What are the most important keywords and headers required in an email to ensure the delivery to the major email service providers.***

Also any other techniques; links to whitelist forms that allow you to submit your servers' IP(s)..etc will be a bonus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Don't use a fake address, that's reeks of spam

2) Set up [DomainKeys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DKIM) for your domain

3) Set up [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) for your domain

Comment: Good Response. I'll give it another 24 hours to see other replies before accepting as finally answer. Thanks for your input.